# Do I need to hold a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK in the onReceive method for a CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcast?

Tags: android, connectivity, android-wake-lock

I have a Service that listens to network connectivity changes using the ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION intent filter. Should I acquire a partial cpu lock at the beginning of my onReceive method to process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to hold a wake lock for the broadcast receiver itself, android will do that for you.

But if you need to do anything long lasting, you will need to spawn a new service inside onReceive, at which time you should acquire a wake lock on the service.

also look at the documentation to make sure you only hold locks to system resources you really need (mostly just cpu) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: "you don't need to hold a wake lock for the broadcast receiver itself, android will do that for you" : Are you sure `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` will wake the receiver ? see : [BroadcastReceiver behavior when phone is asleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254420/broadcastreceiver-behavior-when-phone-is-asleep)