# Android BroadcastReceiver and deep sleep

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-wake-lock

Can Android go to deep sleep while it is processing a broadcast in BroadcastRceiver?
Is it required to create a partial wakelock as early as possible in BroadcastReceiver onReceive method or it can be created anywhere in onReceive method (and passed to a service)?

AlarmManager documentation states `The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm receiver's onReceive() method is executing. This guarantees that the phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast.` But what about other broadcasts? Or is this dependent only on sender of the broadcast?

Comment: If the device is already asleep it may not even wake up to receive the broadcast : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254420/broadcastreceiver-behavior-when-phone-is-asleep

Answer (score 1):

> Can Android go to deep sleep while it is processing a broadcast in BroadcastRceiver?

Generally, yes. One notable exception is if the `BroadcastReceiver` was triggered by `AlarmManager` and a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`.

> Is it required to create a partial wakelock as early as possible in BroadcastReceiver onReceive method or it can be created anywhere in onReceive method (and passed to a service)?

Well, you cannot pass a `WakeLock` to a service very easily, which is why I wrote [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

> But what about other broadcasts? Or is this dependent only on sender of the broadcast?

I am not aware of any other broadcast `Intent` that automatically holds a `WakeLock`, besides the aforementioned `AlarmManager` scenario. One that *might* would be `SMS_RECEIVED`, as an incoming SMS can also wake up the device.

Comment: In my case these are AIRPLANE_MODE broadcasts sent from various applications trying to control it. Btw I tried to insert a Thread.sleep() in beginning of broadcast receiver and results surprised me - looks like phone didn't do to deep sleep during delay...

Comment: But anyway - I will acquire wake lock in beginning of broadcast receiver if I won't find any references to official Android documentation stating that broadcast receivers processing broadcasts prevent phone from sleeping.